# Flex/Actionscript 3: Is it possible to generate a class at runtime that inherits from another class?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'd like to be able to generate a class that inherits from BitmapData at runtime. Is this possible in Actionscript 3? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more logical to proceed by composition ?

Comment: Tell that to the dude who implemented the Tree control, or pretty much any part of the image asset handling system (Embedding, I'm looking at you).

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Maybe you can ask your real question instead? Eg, "How do I create icons for a Flex 3 Tree control at runtime?"

Comment: Because creating a dynamic class that extends an existing is an interesting problem that would happen to solve my "real" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you will find yet a mature library to do that. There are two open source projects for dealing with ABC bytecode manipulation but they seems to be in infancy. You can take a look on at http://code.google.com/p/flemit/ and http://code.google.com/p/floxy/

Answer (score 1):

As the author of flemit / floxy (though both were only created for [asmock](http://asmock.sourceforge.net/)), I would recommend looking into [AS3Commons Bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html) as it is under active development (flemit/floxy are not).

AS3Commons Bytecode is actually based on the [Loom](http://code.google.com/p/loom-as3/) project and has been extended to use a much cleaner API than flemit was ever intended to have.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that, but you could probably mimic that sort of behavior with a static class that you can feed standard BitmapData objects into at runtime...